# Training Word2Vec is extremely slow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, word2vec

I'm currently trying to train a Word2Vec skip-gram model with negative sampling using keras from tensorflow 2.0 based on [this tutorial](https://adventuresinmachinelearning.com/word2vec-keras-tutorial/) (without the auxiliary output). My model looks like this:

```
# vocab_size = about 1 million
# embedding_dim = 300

# Target word and context word as integers
input_target = keras.Input((1,))
input_context = keras.Input((1,))

# Retrieve word embeddings of target and context word
embeddings = keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size + 1, embedding_dim, input_length=1, name="embeddings")
embedding_target = embeddings(input_target)
embedding_context = embeddings(input_context)

# Reshape embeddings
reshape = keras.layers.Reshape((embedding_dim, 1))
embedding_target = reshape(embedding_target)
embedding_context = reshape(embedding_context)

# Compute dot product of embedding vectors
dot = keras.layers.Dot(1)([embedding_target, embedding_context])
dot = keras.layers.Reshape((1,))(dot)

# Compute output
output = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(dot)

# Create mode
model = keras.Model(inputs=[input_target, input_context], outputs=output)
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="rmsprop")
```

The data set I'm using is the [english wikipedia data set](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/wikipedia) provided by tensorflow. However I do not train on the full data set (5,824,596 articles), just on 3,000,000 articles. As you can imagine, the number of unique words (~1 million) and the total number of words (~1.2 billion) are still huge. However the authors of the [original Word2Vec paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.3781.pdf) state in the abstract that learning high quality word vectors of a corpus of 1.6 billion words takes less than a day.
My implementation needs 3 seconds per article to train on average. This looks really slow to me as it would take more than 100 days to train on all 3 million articles once.
I have an Nvidia GTX 1080 TI, and `nvidia-smi` shows that the GPU utilization is at 0% most of the time with short "peaks" to about 5%.

My first thought was that the preprocessing steps are too slow. So I tested the training with dummy-data generated with numpy:

```
target = np.random.randint(0, vocab_size, 2048 * 1000, np.int32)
context = np.random.randint(0, vocab_size, 2048 * 1000, np.int32)
label = np.random.randint(0, 2, 2048 * 1000, np.int32)

model.fit([target, context], label, 4096)
```

I tested different values for batch_size (32, 1024, 2048, 4096), but the GPU utilization was still at 0% most of the time. The whole `target`, `context` and `label` arrays fit into memory.

As I changed the `fit` method to `train_on_batch` (but with no batching - put the whole arrays into the function) the GPU utilization at least varied between 0% and almost 40%.

Besides `tensorflow-gpu` is installed and tensorflow does recognize the GPU: `2020-03-13 15:44:52.424589: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1304] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 10349 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:b1:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)`

Am I missing something obvious? Could be possible as I'm new to keras/tensorflow and to machine learning in general.

Comment: Note that GPUs aren't necessarily preferred for word-vector training, as the large vocabularies give rise to models that typically don't fit in GPU memory, and thus training speed may be severely limited by bandwidth to GPU memory. If you mainly need word-vectors (rather than a `keras` learning-exercise) I'd suggest using an established word2vec implementation, such as the one in the `gensim` library.

Comment: Glancing over that tutorial – I'm not a `keras` expert, but I doubt it represents `keras` best practices. The creation of giant `couples` & `labels` arrays in memory, to drive all training, as 1 step before any training begins looks inefficient & likely to only work for tiny datasets. (Might your slowness be due to massive virtual-memory swapping?) The 'main training loop' uses inconsistent variable names (`i`?) that may render it non-executable, & example output ("200,000" iterations) is fishy – word2vec more often trains on 5-20 epochs over the input. I'd look for an alternate tutorial!

Comment: Did you find any solutions, I'm experiencing similar problems. Word2vec training in gensim on Brown dataset takes just a couple of seconds but with pyTorch it takes about 5 hours.